# RevenueCat | want to match firebase authenticated users with Revenuecat

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I want to match the user that is authenticated with Firebase with the users whom did an in-app purchase with RevenueCat. Even though i follow the steps with Provide App User ID on configuration in RevenueCat docs RC dashboard still shows a hashed value for users who purchased a product. Is there a way to make sure the data match and can see the details for users?

I tried implementing the ins in RC docs.